# Run cmd file using python

Tags: python

I have a cmd file "file.cmd" containing 100s of lines of command.

Example

```
 pandoc --extract-media -f docx -t gfm "sample1.docx" -o "sample1.md"
 pandoc --extract-media -f docx -t gfm "sample2.docx" -o "sample2.md"
 pandoc --extract-media -f docx -t gfm "sample3.docx" -o "sample3.md"
```

I am trying to run these commands using a script so that I don't have to go to a file and click on it.
This is my code, and it results in no output:

```
file1 = open('example.cmd', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines()
# print(Lines)
for i in Lines:
    print(i)
    os.system(i)
```

Comment: You should use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module for this.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by 'nothing happens' (and I note that it has now been modified to 'it results in no output' but this edit appears to be by a different contributor, so I'm confused as to whether to trust it). How are you running this script? What actions do you take and what exactly do you see happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read the cmd file line by line. you can simply try the following:

```
import os
os.system('myfile.cmd')
```

or using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['myfile.cmd'], shell = True, close_fds = True)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Example:

**myfile.cmd**:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Grettings From Python!
PAUSE
```

**script.py**:

```
import os
os.system('myfile.cmd')
```

The cmd will open with:

```
Greetings From Python!
Press any key to continue ...
```

You can debug the issue by knowing the return exit code by:

```
import os
return_code=os.system('myfile.cmd')
assert return_code == 0 #asserts that the return code is 0 indicating success!
```

*Note: os.system works by calling `system()` in C can only take up to 65533 arguments after a command (so it is a 16 bit issue). Giving one more argument will result in the return code `32512 (which implies the exit code 127).`*

Comment: Using os.system('myfile.cmd') it printed 32256 but commands were not run 

Using p = subprocess.Popen(['myfile.cmd']) I got PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: try running the script `as admin` on windows or if using linux add `sudo` before running it

Comment: If you are going to use `Popen`, then afterwards: `return_code = p.wait()` to await the completion.

Comment: Since I am on windows and Jupyter notebook I tried ! p = subprocess.Popen(['myfile.cmd']) and got this output [/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")]

Comment: then you have syntax errors in your cmd file. kindly share your file

Comment: @JohnC. but whenever I go and click open "myfile.cmd"  the command runs

Comment: what's the exit return code. when you run the cmd file.is it 0?  How did you know that they run successfully?

Comment: Whenever I click open cmd prompt opens and commands run and they return md file

Comment: [@ECHO OFF
ECHO Grettings From Python!
PAUSE]
 edited my file with this and tried running  [os.system('myfile.cmd')]  I got this output and nothing else 
OUT: 32512

Comment: 32512 probably means that the command has not been found. one way to solve this is to do the following. add a variable `cmd= "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"` then use it as `os.system(cmd + "myfile.cmd")` . please tell if it worked

Comment: still got 32512

Answer (score 0):

The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function (`os.system('command')`).

since it is a command file (`cmd`), and only the shell can run it, then shell argument must set to be true. since you are setting the shell argument to true, the command needs to be string form and not a list.

use the `Popen` method for spawn a new process and the communicte for waiting on that process (you can time it out as well). if you whish to communicate with the child process, provide the `PIPES` (see mu example, but you dont have to!)

**the code below for python 3.3 and beyond**

```
import subprocess

try:
    proc=subprocess.Popen('myfile.cmd', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)  #timing out the execution, just if you want, you dont have to!
except TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    outs, errs = proc.communicate()
```

**for older python versions**

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('myfile.cmd', shell=True)
t=10
while proc.poll() is None and t >= 0:
    print('Still waiting')
    time.sleep(1)
    t -= 1

proc.kill()
```

In both cases (python versions) if you dont need the `timeout` feature and you dont need to interact with the child process, then just, use:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('myfile.cmd', shell=True)
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: I got these errors trying to run your code. Do I need to import any modules [NameError: name 'proc' is not defined], [NameError: name 'TimeoutExpired' is not defined]

Comment: sorry, you need to import subprocess. i have updated my code

Comment: what is your python version ?

Comment: version 3 I am on jupyter notebook

Comment: see my fixes, i have typo in proc in the first code snippet. make sure to take the last updated code and run it again please. make sure your python version is greater than 3.3

Comment: I am on python version beyond 3.3 
[/usr/bin/python3
3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0]] so tried your first solution. Unfortunately there was no output but also no error message